# VS2012 $(exists) only accepts scalar values

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

Okay, this is more of a build error than a programming error. I have never had much reason to get my hands dirty with builds, so this error is baffling me.

I have tried googling this error with little results, the responses are either nonexistent, incomprehensible or not applicable.

The error is:

```
The "exists" function only accepts a scalar value, but its argument 
"$(PackageSourceManifest)" evaluates to "[same path];[same path]" which is not a 
scalar value. C:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\
                                   v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets
```

Anyway, I dug into Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets and I found the line where it is erroring out. I have verbose builds on where I was attempting to see if I could find anything that stuck out to me that I could fix.

Nothing.

I have googled how to change Package Source Manifests, I have looked in Build Properties, I have searched for a source manifest or even something that says source manifest, nothing. Maybe I am looking too hard or maybe I just don't know what to look for.

Any ideas on how to fix this and what caused this?

Comment: `[same path];[same path]` is the problem, there can only be one path.

Comment: Can you get what `$(PackageSourceManifest)` resolves to?

Comment: In the end, I just created a new project. It compiles fine now. I assume converting between Visual Studio versions and framework versions, something got messed up.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Open your **.csproj file and look for any duplicated import tag**.

In my case the .csproj had two lines like this:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio
\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

Remove one of them fixed the problem.

Answer (score 13):

Had the same issue in VS 2012 -

```
Error   48  04115: The "exists" function only accepts a scalar value, but its argument "@(_UnmanagedRegistrationCache)" evaluates to "obj\TheQueueData.sqlproj.UnmanagedRegistration.cache;obj\TheQueueData.sqlproj.UnmanagedRegistration.cache" which is not a scalar value.   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets  1091    7   TheQueueData
```

Closing and re-opening the solution did the trick for me.

Comment: 2015 - worked for me too. after removing the local db file i started getting this issue

Comment: Worked for me as well. Cheers

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, due to improper import of **$MSBuildExtensionsPath32$**. It's obvious that **v10.0** is for **VS2010** whereas you're on VS2012 (v11.0).

Therefore, change your import to:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

For other, if you have **VS2013 (v12.0)**, you can change it to:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

*Note: if your remove this line like @giacomelli suggested, you'll not be able to use define your custom target file.*

From MSDN : **MSBuildExtensionsPath32**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx

> Introduced in the .NET Framework 4: there is no difference between the
>   default values of MSBuildExtensionsPath and MSBuildExtensionsPath32.
>   You can set the environment variable MSBUILDLEGACYEXTENSIONSPATH to a
>   non-null value to enable the behavior of the default value of
>   MSBuildExtensionsPath in earlier versions. In the .NET Framework 3.5
>   and earlier, the default value of MSBuildExtensionsPath points to the
>   path of the MSBuild subfolder under the \Program Files\ or \Program
>   Files (x86) folder, depending on the bitness of the current process.
>   For example, for a 32-bit process on a 64-bit machine, this property
>   points to the \Program Files (x86) folder. For a 64-bit process on a
>   64-bit machine, this property points to the \Program Files folder. Do
>   not include the final backslash on this property. This location is a
>   useful place to put custom target files. For example, your target
>   files could be installed at \Program
>   Files\MSBuild\MyFiles\Northwind.targets and then imported in project
>   files by using this XML code:

Answer (score 1):

I think this happened to me when I a tried to Web Publish a project in VS2012 that had originally been a VS2010 project. So recreating the project in VS2012 is a way to cure it. 
Or as @Giacomelli mentions, deleting the reference to the v10.0 targets. Note that `V10.0` = `VS2010` and `v11.0`= `VS2012`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in VS2013. I had no duplicates. The solution that worked for me was clearing the Visual Studio cache. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in VS2013, but only when I try to rebuild the project. Below how I solve the problem in my conditions, I hope that is also useful to other people.

**Configuration:**

- I have my typescript files in separate projects in the solution.
- Those projects were migrate for VS 2012.

**Cause**:
when I click on the error in Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets files I discovered that the project was using the VS2012 version of those files. That is the projects where only partially migrated form VS2012 to VS2013.

**Solution**: 
Open the typescript project (first unload project) 
Search for:

```
      <PropertyGroup>
        <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">12.0</VisualStudioVersion>
        <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
      </PropertyGroup>
```

- Comment the line VSToolsPath
- Save and close the file
- Reload the project You can see a migration
  screen from visual studio notifying you that the project was upgrade.

  rebuild the project, now should work

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same problem and checking my .csproj file I found nothing wrong, no duplicate imports - nothing.

After stumbling 30 minutes I got it fixed by opening my .csproj file and rearranging  tags in it.

Initially I moved them all to the top, but got an error message that OutputPath is not defined, then I moved all of them right below the  where they were defined and everything worked. All of them except:

Most probably moving NuGet.targets from the bottom of the file was what actually fixed it. I have no idea, nor I want to waste more time.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: For me, just closing, reopening and rebuilding the project worked.