# Error while building asp.net mvc website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been battling this for days and I cant seem to figure out what is the problem...
I have an Asp.NET mvc 4 web site which works perfect but when I try to deploy it to azure I get this error:

```
Error   2   The "exists" function only accepts a scalar value, but its 
argument "$(PackageSourceManifest)" evaluates to "D:\Software 
Projects\xxx\xxx\xxxWebSite\obj\Debug\Package\xxxWebSite.SourceManifest.xml
;D:\Software Projects\xxx\xxx\xxxWebSite\obj\Debug\Package\xxxWebSite.
SourceManifest.xml" which is not a scalar value.
```

This happens also whe I try to clean and rebuilt, So  i guess its not the azure deployment process giving me trouble. I have no idea how to handle this and this website is supposed to go live tomorow :(

Comment: Have you checked the answers on this question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006428/vs2012-exists-only-accepts-scalar-values

Comment: @nozari I did, late last night... trying it now

Answer (score 0):

Create a backup first. :)
<hack>The `D:\Software 
Projects\xxx\xxx\xxxWebSite\obj\Debug\Package\xxxWebSite.SourceManifest.xml` path may be repeated twice somewhere in the depths of the project (or publish or package or magic) settings, where it should be only once. Search for it (the uglier the config is, the closer you might actually be), and recursively try to remove anything connected to it that might be repeated.</hack>

I would try this if I hadn't found anything more comprehensible. Worst case: try recreating the project...

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when Previewing a web deploy. I fixed it by re-entering the Connection password. I probably recreated some files somewhere, which fixed the issue.